# ESP32 Arduino Bluetooth Serial does not reconnect after disconnecting

Tags: arduino, serial, bluetooth, esp32

The basic ESP32 Arduino Bluetooth Serial example pairs and connects as expected, BUT once I disconnect the Bluetooth terminal it stops responding to new events at all. Once I reset the ESP32, it starts working again with the same problem. (It doesn't matter if it keeps being paired or not.)

I have tested it with the Windows Bluetooth terminal and with the Bluetooth Any terminal (from the windows store.)

I have downloaded the latest ESP32-Arduino library from GitHub and I still get the same problem.

I have tested it with several ESP32 modules, and they all respond with the same problem.

It looks like a bug in the library code.

See the simple Arduino example code below:

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Does anyone know of another Bluetooth serial library that does work?